# logging.*'s @ConfigurationProperties in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In Spring-boot, which class reads the `logging.*` in application.yml ?

```
for (String name : applicationContext.getBeanNamesForAnnotation(ConfigurationProperties.class)) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
```

I tried the above code, but the one I'm looking for is not listed. [spring-docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) doesn't mention it. No luck searching the [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/search?q=%40ConfigurationProperties%28prefix%20%3D%20%22logging&unscoped_q=%40ConfigurationProperties%28prefix%20%3D%20%22logging).

**First (specific) question:** how to find the class who reads and auto-configures logging.* properties?

**Second (much wider) question:** how to find the respective `@ConfigurationProperties` for a specific module in spring-boot?

**Output**

```
server-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties
spring.http-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpProperties
spring.mvc-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcProperties
spring.task.execution-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionProperties
spring.resources-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ResourceProperties
spring.jta-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.JtaProperties
spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties
spring.jpa.hibernate-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties
spring.jpa-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties
diskSpaceHealthIndicatorProperties
management.health.status-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorProperties
management.endpoint.health-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointProperties
management.endpoint.configprops-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpointProperties
management.endpoints.jmx-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.jmx.JmxEndpointProperties
management.endpoints.web-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.WebEndpointProperties
management.endpoint.env-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.env.EnvironmentEndpointProperties
spring.info-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoProperties
management.info-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.info.InfoContributorProperties
management.endpoint.logfile-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.logging.LogFileWebEndpointProperties
management.metrics-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MetricsProperties
management.metrics.export.simple-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.simple.SimpleProperties
management.trace.http-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.trace.http.HttpTraceProperties
spring.gson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonProperties
spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties
spring.data.rest-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestProperties
spring.hateoas-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HateoasProperties
spring.jdbc-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcProperties
spring.task.scheduling-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskSchedulingProperties
spring.transaction-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionProperties
spring.servlet.multipart-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MultipartProperties
spring.devtools-org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.DevToolsProperties
management.endpoints.web.cors-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.CorsEndpointProperties
management.server-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementServerProperties
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring boot's logging classes are in the [`org.springframework.boot.logging`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/logging) package. It doesn't work using the `@ConfigurationProperties` method that you've been searching for. Logging properties are transferred to environment variables in the [`LoggingSystemProperties`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/logging/LoggingSystemProperties.java) class and then those environment variables are referenced in the provider's configuration file, e.g. the [logback XML config files](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback).